# React context in MPA (one context for different apps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm rendering several react "snippets" on one page

```
ReactDOM.render(<MainNavSearchApp />, document.getElementById('main-nav-search-app'));
ReactDOM.render(<NavSearchBrandsApp />, document.getElementById('main-nav-search-brands-app'));
```

and want to use one context for them

```
class MainNavSearchApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavSearchContextProvider>
                    <MainNavSearch />
                </NavSearchContextProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default MainNavSearchApp; 

class NavSearchBrandsApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavSearchContextProvider>
                    <NavSearchBrands />
                </NavSearchContextProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NavSearchBrandsApp;
```

but if I update the context in on of the apps, it does not get updated in the other. As I understand, React creates two "clone" independent contexts. Can multiple instances use the same context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as [data in React flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down), they must have a common parent in order to share same context data.

> This is commonly called a “top-down” or “unidirectional” data flow. Any state is always owned by some specific component, and any data or UI derived from that state can only affect components “below” them in the tree.

Therefore, the common parent should use [`ReactDOM.createPortal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), and render the provider, while other components will be his children.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="app1"></div>
    <div id="app2"></div>
</body>
```

```
// Common parent - MUST
function Root() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={42}>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<App1 />, document.getElementById("app1"))}
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<App2 />, document.getElementById("app2"))}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

// MainNavSearchApp
function App1() {
  const val = React.useContext(Context);
  return <>App1: {val}</>;
}

// NavSearchBrandsApp
function App2() {
  const val = React.useContext(Context);
  return <>App2: {val}</>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]